# Nested IFs in function not working

Tags: excel

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to input a function in C2 in order to assign a numerical value to the minutes given in Column B. The criteria for this can be seen in the image above (starting at G1).

I have tried using a formula I copied from a similar situation but is not working:

=IF(B2<=$A$2,5,IF(B2<=$A$3,4,IF(B2<=$A$4,3,IF(B2<=$A$5,2,1))))

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: If you want to retain the *X min* format, select the cells and tap `Ctrl+1`. On the *Number* tab choose *Custom* from the list and supply *0" min"* or *0 \m\i\n* for the *Type:*. This will allow you to put integers into the cells for calculation while retaining your preferred format. e.g. *150 min*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion by @Jeeped above will simplify the formulas needed.  If you have to keep the 'A' and 'B' cells as they are listed above, you have to extract the number from the 'x min' format and convert the 'x' to a number so it can be compared (I assume a " " exists after the number.  Could search for " min" as well).

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2)-1))
```

Using the above, if A2 = '60 min', the formula will produce a '60'.

Now that the cell contents can be treated as numbers, the comparisons can be made.  Formula for C2:

```
=IF(VALUE(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)-1))<=VALUE(LEFT($A$2,SEARCH(" ",$A$2)-1)),5,   
 IF(VALUE(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)-1))<=VALUE(LEFT($A$3,SEARCH(" ",$A$3)-1)),4, 
 IF(VALUE(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)-1))<=VALUE(LEFT($A$4,SEARCH(" ",$A$4)-1)),3,  
 IF(VALUE(LEFT(B2,SEARCH(" ",B2)-1))<=VALUE(LEFT($A$5,SEARCH(" ",$A$5)-1)),2,1))))
```

This is ugly, but works given the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula (in this case for C2):

```
=SUM((B2<=$A$2:$A$5)*1)+1
```

It is important to use it as array formula. So after typing or inserting this formula to your cell don't just commit with Return but hit Ctrl+Shift+Return. If you did it right, your formula will be surrounded by curly brackets in formula bar:

```
{=SUM((B2<=$A$2:$A$5)*1)+1}
```

Comment: I don't know where the 'Should be' values come from. They are in dispcrepancy to the verbalized conditions (column G) to which my formula refers.

Comment: Those are the scores I manually inputted, the scores to the left under Wrong Score are the scores I got from the formula I used but are incorrect. I put 'What the scores should be' there simply as reference.

Comment: What do you get? A wrong result or an error. And are you really sure that you entered it as array formula, not as normal formula. if it is a normal formula you get false results.